# Phonegap build final apk file locally without phonegap build website

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

I use Phonegap CLI to make my android apps every thing works fine, but when I want to make my final .apk I face a problem

I have SDK JDK Java and all environment variables

I generated my .keystore and when i run `phonegap build --release` i have no error my problem is this
there is no folder called `bin` or any .apk file in my folder

I red all documents and questions from stackoverflow and I still have this problem

what do you think? should i switch to cordova CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap [has been discontinued](https://blog.phonegap.com/update-for-customers-using-phonegap-and-phonegap-build-cc701c77502c).

Switching to Cordova CLI is certainly an option, but many find that installing the build toolchain is [a lot of trouble](https://medium.com/@ghenne/why-use-a-build-service-fa08f29c0941) to get working (and keep working).

If you prefer the convenience of a build service like you had with PhoneGap, have a look at [VoltBuilder](https://volt.build/), Ionic or Monaca.